# How to save a file for which I have no write permissions?

Tags: save, command-line

Sometimes it happens that I open a file and make some modifications as my own
user, without noticing or "forgetting" to noticing the `[read-only]` warning in
the status line (ie. some random `/etc` config file like `/etc/resolv.conf`).

`:w!` obviously fails in this case because my user has no write permission
anyway.  So I have to `:w /home/filename`, exit and `sudo mv ...`, very
uncomfortable.

Is there a way so that I escalate temporarily to root to be able to save the
file currently opened? (given I am in `sudoers` or/and I can `su` directly)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The trick is to use an external call to `sudo`:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

How this works:

- `:w !<command>` executes `<command>` with the contents of the buffer as stdin.
- `tee` duplicates stdin to a file & stdout; `%` expands to the current filename..
- You prefix this with `sudo` for root permissions.

You're not *really* saving the file with Vim, rather, you're calling an external program to overwrite the contents of the file you're editing. This is why you will get a warning from Vim:

```
W12: Warning: File "xxx" has changed and the buffer was changed in Vim as well
See ":help W12" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

You could turn this into a function:

```
fun! SuperWrite()
        write !sudo tee %
        " Or with :silent (but that doesn't seem to work for everyone)
        "silent write !sudo tee %
        edit!
endfun
```

And keybind:

```
nnoremap <Leader>w! :call SuperWrite()<CR>
```

With `su`, only the root user can use `-c` to immediately execute a command. I don't think you can use `su` to do this, but perhaps there is a trick I am unaware of...

Comment: `SuperWrite` works, but it echoes the file back at you. Running it `:silent`ly has you enter your password invisibly.

Comment: @TankorSmash Thanks; updated answer. Not sure what you mean with "enter your password invisibly", though? Adding `silent` seems to work fine?

Comment: I don't run vim with sudo, so that may be at play here, but when I go to sudo tee the file, it prompts me for the sudo password. If its silent, I don't see the prompt, but still need to enter a password.

Comment: What you're seeing is tee's standard functionality of echoing to stdout as well as the file given.  A solution is to redirect stdout to /dev/null, a la:

    `w ! tee % > /dev/null`

This will still echo the result of the command (a single line), but not the entire buffer contents.

Comment: Rather than using `tee` then throwing away its output, wouldn't `cat` also work if you don't want the file printed out?

Comment: See also: [How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2600783/55075)

Comment: How to get rid of W12 warning?

Answer (score 12):

I use the following mapping in my .vimrc, which I find useful:

```
cnoremap w!! w !sudo tee %
```

It's easy to remember, because `w` is "write," `w!` is "force write," and `w!!` is "super-duper-force write." :P

Comment: I've long had it mapped to `W`, but `w!!` makes much more sense, shall update my .vimrc. Thanks